# Expand completions automatically in fish shell?

Tags: fish

I wonder if its possible to automatically expand completions menu, which arrives if you hit `<tab>`? To basically check for autocompletion under cursor every time you enter character, and not only when you hit tab? Thx.

Comment: Sounds like you should be making a feature request on the github repo

Answer (score 0):

Internaly fish tab completions are done by a fish binding:
`bind -k btab complete-and-search`

The wildcard binding is bound to self-insert:
`bind '' self-insert`
self insert adds the captured char passed from bind '' to the current command,
so when `a` is pressed it inserts `a`.

The bind command accepts more than one command, so to do this you would need
to wrap `__fish_complete_command` (Or whatever internal completion fucntion)
and bind it something like this `bind '' self-insert command_complete_wrapper`
Because in reality, youd would not want to bind to every input, only
a sane subset.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I know and already done that. The problem with that is that in fish there's no separate command to invoke pager completion, it wrapped into autosuggestion feature, so that if there's only one completion left - instead of pager it will expand. I created issue on fish github page if you interested.

Comment: Cool, I'll be watching that issue.